# How do you get a certain block of code (in Java) to keep repeating until the user chooses to exit?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

For example, in the code below, how do I make it such that I can keep running the "enter username" part until the user chooses to exit?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EnterUserName {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner user1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your username: ");

        String userName = user1.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Username: " + userName);
    }
}
```

Comment: a possible solution is a `while` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How should the user indicate they would like to exit?  If they just end the process themselves, you don't need to do anything, just put it inside a while loop like so:

```
public class EnterUserName {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner user1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userName;

        while (true) { //loop forever
            System.out.println("Enter your username: ");

            userName = user1.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Username: " + userName);
        }
    }
}
```

Another option is to just have them enter a special keyword, maybe something like "exit".  This could be implemented like so:

```
public class EnterUserName {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner user1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userName;

        while (true) { //loop forever
            System.out.println("Enter your username: ");

            userName = user1.nextLine();

            if (userName.equals("exit")) { //if the user entered "exit"
                break; //break out of the loop (terminates the program in this case)
            }

            System.out.println("Username: " + userName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a ton! I'm new to code, so I'm still learning these things :)

Answer (score 0):

New to code can be hard.

You can use `break` in a loop (`for` loop, `while` loop, `do while` loop) if you wish your progarm continue the remaining code, or you can use `System.exit(0)` to immediately stop the program.

I am assuming that you do not need validation. If you need it just change `else` to `else if (expression)` in the code expamle

I am also want you to fix the way you naming variables, you should name it like the example for the clarification. And you should declare variables out of a loop `String userName;`, it is a good practice. Here is the code example:

```
public class EnterUserName {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userName;
        while (true) { // Loop forever until correct input or choose "1"
            System.out.println("Enter your username or enter 1 to exit: ");
            userName = input.nextLine();
            if (userName.equals("1")) {
                System.exit(0); // immediately stop the program
//                Or you can use break too. If you use break, "End program" will be printed;
//                break;
            } else { // You can use else if here to have validation of Username
                System.out.println("You have enter Username: " + userName);
                break; // Correct input, break out the loop
            }
        }
        System.out.println("End program");
    }
}
```